# using spark to read specific columns data from hbase

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-spark

I have a table in HBase named as "orders" it has column family 'o' and columns as {id,fname,lname,email}
having row key as id. I am trying to get the value of fname and email only from hbase using spark. Currently what 'i am doing is given below

```
   override def put(params: scala.collection.Map[String, Any]): Boolean = {
    var sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("Connector")
    var sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConfig)
    var hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    hbaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ZookeeperQourum)
    hbaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", zookeeperPort)
    hbaseConfig.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, schemdto.tableName);
    hbaseConfig.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, "o:fname,o:email");
    var hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConfig, classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
    try {
      hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2).map(result => result.raw())
        .map(f => KeyValueToString(f)).saveAsTextFile(sink)

      true
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => false
    }
}


def KeyValueToString(keyValues: Array[KeyValue]): String = {
    var it = keyValues.iterator
    var res = new StringBuilder
    while (it.hasNext) {
      res.append( Bytes.toString(it.next.getValue()) + ",")
    }
    res.substring(0, res.length-1);
}
```

But nothing is returned and If I try to fetch only one column such as

```
hbaseConfig.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, "o:fname");
```

then it returns all the values of column fname

So my question is how to get multiple columns from hbase using spark

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

List of columns to scan needs to be space-delimited, according to the [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormat.html).

```
hbaseConfig.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, "o:fname o:email");
```